# How to show Twitter videos in android native page

Tags: android, video, twitter, embed

I'm displaying `Html contents` in my `native` page. I'm showing the `Tweets`, using `TweeetUi`. But, the `TweeetUi`, doesn't show `twitter videos`. I also, checked the response that we are getting. In response, I couldn't find `video url`. Afetr googling, i found that embeded video support is available only for websites. Is there any workaround to show videos in native page like `tweets` or to get the `video url`, so that, a `custom UI` can be used to show the video.

Thank You

Comment: user **TwiteCore** for displaying _tweet video_

Comment: @DhruvRaval , I'm using TwitterKit and as per Twiiter developers website, (https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/show-tweets.html) only showing tweets is given. How to show twiiter videos. Is there any tutorial?

Comment: no there is no tutorial but i m giving  process(code) of getting twitter video which is based on some conditions through that completely differ from which feed is contain image or  video...

Answer (score 0):

```
TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient().getStatusesService().userTimeline(null, twitterKeyword, 10, null, maxId, null, null, null, false, new Callback<List<Tweet>>() {

            @Override
            public void success(Result<List<Tweet>> result) {

                final List<Tweet> tweets = result.data;

                if(!tweets.isEmpty()) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < tweets.size(); i++) {

                        Tweet t = tweets.get(i);

                        Long idStr = Long.parseLong(t.idStr);
                        String text = t.text;
                        String createdAt = t.createdAt;
                        String favoriteCount = "" + t.favoriteCount;
                        String favorited = "" + t.favorited;
                        String retweetCount = "" + t.retweetCount;
                        String retweeted = "" + t.retweeted;
                        String retweetedStatus = "" + t.retweetedStatus;
                        String name = t.user.name;
                        String profileImageUrl = t.user.profileImageUrl;

                        String mediaImageUrl = null, videoUrl = null;

                        if (t.entities.media != null) {
                            String type = t.entities.media.get(0).type;

                            if (type.equals("photo")) {
                                if(t.entities.media.size() > 0) {
                                    if (t.entities.media.get(0).expandedUrl != null) {
                                        if ((t.entities.media.get(0).expandedUrl).contains("video")) {
                                            videoUrl = t.entities.media.get(0).expandedUrl;
                                            mediaImageUrl = t.entities.media.get(0).mediaUrl;
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            mediaImageUrl = t.entities.media.get(0).mediaUrl;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    mediaImageUrl = "'";
                                    videoUrl = "";
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                mediaImageUrl = "'";
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            if(t.entities.urls.size() > 0) {

                                if(t.entities.urls.get(0).url != null) {
                                    if(text.contains(t.entities.urls.get(0).url)) {
                                        videoUrl = "";
                                        mediaImageUrl="";
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    if (t.entities.urls.get(0).expandedUrl != null) {
                                        videoUrl = t.entities.urls.get(0).expandedUrl;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        videoUrl = "";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                videoUrl = "";
                                mediaImageUrl="";
                            }
                        }

                        System.out.println("mediaImageUrl" + mediaImageUrl);
                        System.out.println("videoUrl" + videoUrl);              
                }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                System.out.println("failure"+ e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

Here, **TwitterCore** -->  *com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore*

Comment: this requires a session..User need to log in. I need to show tweet video, without logging in, like tweets

Comment: ohh.. yes these one require a login in twitter but i am know these way only to getting twitter video ...!!